# Want to check total space occupied by .dmp files lat day in a folder

Tags: linux, unix

I want to know how much space was occupied in linux environment  in a specific folder. want to know what is the space that occupied  by .dmp file in a specific folder on last day or 2 weeks back on this same day  .

```
       Please help me on this . many thanks in advance.
```

Regards,
BCV

Answer (score 1):

This command will show the space used by a file or a folder:

```
du -sh FILENAME
```

For example, to check the space used by the current folder:

```
du -sh .
```

To check the space of all `*.dmp` files in the current folder (`*` matches any character sequence, you can search for "regular expression" for more information):

```
du -sh *.dmp
```

You can use **crontab** to automatically run such a command, and use **>** or **>>** in the command line to redirect the shell screen output to a file.

Start writing a crontab file (use the following command adds entries to crontab, which should take effect right away):

```
 #crontab -e
```

For example, this crontab script calculates all `/home/*.dmp` file sizes and writes (append mode, won't delete old records) them to `1.txt` every day at 4AM:

```
0 4 * * * du -sh /home/*.dmp >> 1.txt
```

PS: I don't know where your dmp files come from, and I just treat them as common files. If they are files from Oracle or another application, the application may have a method to calculate the files' status and record it every day by itself（and may be much easier than writing a crontab command and shell script to control it.

You can also search **man page** about this command and shell scripting.